# Display the 1st image file uploaded to a folder using php

Tags: php

ok so I have this code working that it pulls out all the image files in a folder. There is a folder for each different product that has many images in them I want to pull out the 1st image that was uploaded to each folder and display them all on the same page.  At the minute I am displaying all the images from each folder.

Below is the foreach I am using:

```
  $albums = get_articles($albums);

if (count($albums)==0) {
echo "Sorry, no portfolios.";

} else {

foreach($albums as $article) {  


echo '<img src="uploads/', $article['album_id'], '/', $article['image_id'],    '.', 
$article['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $article['timestamp']), 
'"width="450" height="328"/>';    


}

}
```

Below is the function I am using:

```
function get_articles($albums) {

$albums = array();

$per_page = 9;     

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`album_id`) FROM `albums`") or
die(mysql_error());


     $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

     $page = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? (int)$_GET["page"] : 1;
       $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;



 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `albums`,`images`  WHERE  
 albums.album_id=images.album_id AND code='css' LIMIT $start, $per_page ");



 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $albums[] = array(
    'album_id' => $row['album_id'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'image_id' => $row['image_id'],
    'ext' => $row['ext'],
    'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'],
    'description' => $row['description'],
     'type' => $row['type'],
     'code' => $row['code']




    );

 }
  if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages) {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++) { 
            //echo $x, ' '; 

            echo ($x == $page) ? '<span id="page"><span class="page"><a href="? 
page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></span> ' : '<span class="page"><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>
 </span></span> ';
        }

}
return $albums;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this query you will get the 1st image uploaded of every album :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `albums`,`images`  WHERE albums.album_id=images.album_id AND code='css' group by albums.album_id LIMIT $start, $per_page ");
```